# ASP.net Server.Transfer problem + Images are not getting

Tags: asp.net

Hii,

I can't get the images when i using the `Server.Transfer` to transfer the page

I have a page `Page1.aspx` in a folder `folder1`.In the `folder1` there is another folder `subfolder1` and inside `subfolder1` one page `Page2.aspx`. The images are kept in a folder named `images` that is placed in the `folder1`. Initially i have transfered the page from `Page1.aspx` to `Page2.aspx` that has been successfully done. But when i tried to transfer from the `Page2.aspx` to `Page1.aspx` the images could not loaded. Is there any way to load the image correctly by using the `Server.Transfer` statement

Comment: How are the images supposed to "transfer" to the second page?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that the problem is with `Server.Transfer`. Rather, ensure that all images (I assume you're using WebForms with `Image`-related controls) are loaded via `~/` path prefix:

```
<asp:Image ... ImageUrl="~/folder1/images/image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you requesting the images on the page?

Are you are doing it like this:

```
<img src="images/someimage.png" alt="" />
```

When you do a `Server.Transfer` you are telling the server to return the HTML that generated from the page you are transferring the processing to, **but to leave the client URL alone**.

This means that what you are doing is returning the HTML from `/folder1/page1.aspx` but the browser thinks it is still on `/folder1/subfolder1/page2.aspx`, so if your image requests are as above, the browser is looking for a folder called images under subfolder1.

You should either:

1. Change your image requests to `src="/folder1/images/someimage.png"` where you're explicitly telling the browser to return to the root of the site and start from there.
2. Not use server transfer, but instead look at using Response.Redirect or similar.

Comment: Response.Redirect is what was needed. I'd changed my .aspx page and *that* worked but I wanted to do it from the code behind.